# How Do I Get Config Variables on Shopware 6 Theme To The Storefront

Tags: themes, shopware, shopware6

I am building my own Shopware 6 theme using another Shopware 6 theme as a guide. I noticed the theme developer was able to bring the config.xml variables to the storefront. I discovered this by using the `{{ dump() }}` twig function. How do I do the same for my theme?

Attached is a picture of what I saw.

[image: ssik is the name of the twig variable/array and config as seen in the picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `twig` templates there are a couple of functions you can use to get config values.

`config.xml` setting values:

```
{{ config('MyPlugin.config.nameOfConfigSetting') }}
```

`theme.json` config setting values:

```
{{ theme_config('name-of-theme-setting') }}
```

Comment: I use that one {{ theme_config('name-of-theme-setting') }} to retrieve a text type field. Do you have an idea why the theme is not compiling if I enter special characters into the text field I have? Everytime I enter some especial character or a dot or comma, I get an error and is not possible to compile.