# Shopware 6 Theme Rendering Issue: White Page with No Error Log

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm working on a Shopware 6 theme and encountering an issue where my frontend renders a white page without any errors in the log. The problem occurs when I try to display a value from a custom field defined in my theme.json. Here's a snippet of the Twig code causing the issue:

```
<div class="usp-container">
  <div class="usp">
    <p>{{ sw_config('theme.customUSPField1') }}</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Additional divs -->
</div>
```

The corresponding theme.json configuration for customUSPField1 is as follows:

```
"fields": {
  "customUSPField1": {
    "tab": "header",
    "block": "usp",
    "label": { "de-DE": "USP-Feld 1", "en-GB": "USP Field 1" },
    "type": "text",
    "value": "",
    "editable": true
  }
}
```

I've checked the environment settings and cleared the cache, but the issue persists. Any suggestions to debug this white page problem in Shopware 6 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Shopware are you using? Instead of `sw_config` you can try to use `config()` or `theme_config()` as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76393031/9184970

Comment: Using Shopware 6.5.4.1 theme_config() worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the documentation is wrong at this point. In version 6.5.x this actually works with `theme_config`.

```
<div class="usp-container">
  <div class="usp">
    <p>{{ theme_config('customUSPField1') }}</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Additional divs -->
</div>
```